# Struts Validator: password must match 'mask' or be null - possible?

Tags: struts, validation

I have a struts application that has a form to edit user details. I am using struts validator to validate the user input.

I have 2 input boxes: 'Password' and 'Confirm Password'.

If you fill in those boxes, they must follow password rules.
You can also leave the boxes empty to signify that you are not changing your password.

If have the following code in my validation.xml:

```
            <field property="password"
                depends="required,mask">
            <arg0 key="createUser.password"/>
            <var>
                <var-name>mask</var-name>
                <var-value>^[<![CDATA[^<>\&\r\n\\\"\'\|]]>]+$</var-value>
            </var>
        </field>
```

If you add a password, it must adhere to the mask. If you do not add a password, validation will pass. I need to have an 'either/or' check.. As it stands, validation will pass if the password box is empty. If you add a password that adhere's to the rules, validation rightly fails because password != null. Anyone any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote my own validator in the Form class. Pretty easily done.